# Create dynamic query from Configuration Tables using Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, data-structures

I have a requirement to fetch data dynamically from few tables. So I have 2 configuration tables to store information about these tables. One table contains information on the table list like below:

```
TableName    TableCode    TableColumn
----------------------------------------
 a             a             a1
 a             a             a2
 b             b             b1
 b             b             b2
 b             b             b3
 c             c             c1
 c             c             c2
 d             d             d1
 d             d             d2
```

I have another table that stores the relationship between these tables:

```
RelationshipType    TableCode1    TableCode2    TableColumn1    TableColumn2 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
  inner                a            b              a1             b1
  inner                a            b              a2             b2
  inner                c            d              c1             d1
  inner                c            b              c2             b3
```

Based on the above configuration, I need to create a dynamic query like below:

```
select a.a1, a.a2, b.b1, b.b2, b.b3, c.c1, c.c2, d.d1, d.d2 
from b
inner join a on b.b1 = a.b1 and b.b2 = a.b2
inner join c on b.b3 = c.c2
inner join d on c.c1 = d.d1
```

Now the joins could be inner, left or right and the order of insertion in Relationship table could be any but there will definitely be a relationship between all the tables combined. What is the best optimized way to create a dynamic query? Should I search across the relationship table for the parent most table and then create a tree to find relation with other tables? Should I maintain a sequence in the relationship table to find the parent most table and the corresponding tables?

Comment: Can you please tell which DBMS you are using?

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. select * from relationship_table inner join table_list order by RelationshipType desc, TableCode1, TableCode2 (The ordering of RelationshipType is because performing inner joins first is always good. And ordering of TableCodes is because if the next relation also involves the same tables, the condition needs to be concatenated)
2. loop through every row, if previous table code and the current table code is same, add only condition to 'conditionstring' . If not, add a new join with a table names and condition to 'conditionstring'. add the columns to the 'columnlist'.
3. Now 'select' + columnlist + 'from' + conditionstring should give you the query

Hope this helps you